# How to update many to many Django REST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How would I go about updating a many to many relationship in Django REST framework?

Here is my model.

```
class SchoolTeacher(AbstractBase):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
         related_name='teachers')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
         related_name='teacher_at',)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(SchoolSubject, 
        related_name='teachers')
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class SchoolTeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   ....
   def create(self, validated_data):
    school_class = validated_data.get('school_class', None)
    stream = validated_data.get('stream', None)

    school_teacher_model_fields = [
        f.name for f in SchoolTeacher._meta.get_fields()]
    valid_teacher_data = {
        key: validated_data[key]
        for key in school_teacher_model_fields
        if key in validated_data.keys()
    }
    subjects = valid_teacher_data.pop('subjects')
    teacher = SchoolTeacher.objects.create(**valid_teacher_data)

    for subject in subjects:
        teacher.subjects.add(subject)

    self.add_class_teacher(stream, school_class, teacher)

    return teacher

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    subjects = validated_data.pop('subjects')
    school_class = validated_data.get('school_class', None)
    stream = validated_data.get('stream', None)
    teacher = instance

    for (key, value) in validated_data.items():
        setattr(teacher, key, value)

    for subject in subjects:
        teacher.subjects.add(subject)

    teacher.save()

    return teacher
```

How do I achieve updating `subjects`? Currently, I can only add and not delete existing subjects.

Comment: Do you want to have only new subjects save to teacher that is passed in update request payload and delete old  subjects from teacher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround. I wish however someone would post a better answer. The idea here is to delete all subjects first then add them. However, since of course we cannot do `teacher.subjects.all().delete()`, we can do

```
    for existing_subject in teacher.subjects.all():
        teacher.subjects.remove(existing_subject)

    for subject in subjects:
        teacher.subjects.add(subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

As we are talking about many-to-many, both objects need to be persisted before you can assign them to each other.

Once you have that, you can simply add one to the regarding collection of the other, like this (source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
a1 = Article(headline='Django lets you build Web apps easily')
a1.save()
p1 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
p1.save()
a1.publications.add(p1)
```

Or, in one step:

```
new_publication = a1.publications.create(title='Highlights for Children')
```

I haven't found out how to express "contains" yet, but the next step is to remove the subjects that are not in the new list and add the ones that are in the new but not the old list. Probably more efficient with sorted lists or better hashes. But my python is not good enough for that yet.

Comment: This is no different from what I am doing above, I want to update (PUT or PATCH which means deleting a subject if it's not included in the payload), not just adding subjects.

Comment: @GrovelOde Then what is your question?

Comment: @GrovelOde Ok I think I get it now - what you're requesting is two subsets - you want to remove the subjects that aren't in the new list and add the subjects that are in the new list but not in the old one. I haven't found out yet how to do that (the "contains" operation), but that's what you could try. But removing and re-adding all will be just as fine I guess.