# How the updating of m2m fields are working? Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have code where `Product` model has M2M field `Comment` model. I made methods in `views.py` for getting `Product` by `id` and all objects of `Product`, but there's problem with updating it. I can't fully understand how to update `Product` comments field. I already tried a lot of different answers and ideas, but nothing helps me. I'm using **`PUT`** method for update.

**My main questions:**

- Where and how target `Product id` in order to update comments field in it?
- After I find `Product` by it's `id` how I can update M2M field comments in it?

**I tried:**

[Completely Lost: Many To Many with Serializers and Update in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900305/completely-lost-many-to-many-with-serializers-and-update-in-django-rest-framewo)

Doesn't work at all, screams for **`'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'id'`**

[Django Rest update many to many by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417253/django-rest-update-many-to-many-by-id/55043187#55043187)

It's making `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` which is not correct for me.

[How to update many to many Django REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852989/how-to-update-many-to-many-django-rest)

Not enough information in answer, got stuck on it.

I [read](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), but found no usefull information on my problem

**products/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from comments.models import Comment


# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default="No description")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=100, max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    photo_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    photo_two = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    photo_three = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    photo_four = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    is_popular = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_hit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_sale = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**comments/models.py**

```
import uuid

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="default")
    text = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __string__(self):
        return self.username
```

**products/serializers.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        submitted_comments = validated_data.get('comments')
        if submitted_comments:
            for comment in submitted_comments:
                comment_instance = Comment.objects.get(id=comment.id)
                instance.children.add(comment_instance)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'text', 'rating')
```

**products/views.py**

```
import django_filters
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveUpdateAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Product
from .pagination import CustomPagination
from .serializers import ProductSerializer


class GetProductById(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_class = ProductFilter
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_product(self, pk):
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            content = {
                'status': 'Not Found'
            }
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return product

    def get(self, request, pk):
        product = self.get_product(pk)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product_id = django_filters.UUIDFilter(name='id')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id']


class GetProducts(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        return products

    def get(self, request):
        products = self.get_queryset()
        paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(products)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(paginate_queryset, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

***products/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/products/', views.GetProducts.as_view(), name='get_products'),
    path('api/product/<pk>/', views.GetProductById.as_view(), name='get_put_product')
]
```

I expect successful target by `Product id` and finding product.comments field

I expect successful adding new `Comment` to `Product` in it's comments field

Comment: Are you getting errors? You're telling us what you want but not what your code is currently doing.

Comment: @dirkgroten If I try code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900305/completely-lost-many-to-many-with-serializers-and-update-in-django-rest-framewo) I get error **`'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'id'`**, even if it has an id. In other cases I create `Comment` not in m2m field of `Product`.